# Drupal 7 "Page not found. The requested page "/" could not be found" after enabling module

Tags: 7

While enabling a module (Imagecache External), Drupal showed an error related to memory limit, then the site crashed. I'm unable to login anymore, since any page shows now:

> Page not found. The requested page "/" could not be found.

I get the same result when I try to go http://www.example.com/index.php?q=user.

`phpinfo()` says mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

After extensive research I managed to solve this issue. The following info was helpful:
https://www.drupal.org/node/262892

What I did:

1. Disabled the problem module in the system table in SQL, by setting
   the status field of the suspect module to 0 in the {system} table.
2. Rebuilded Database menu system to get access again, by running update.php. The update.php by default don't allow to access, so I need to edit **settings.php** (located in /sites/default/) and change
   `$update_free_access = FALSE;` to `TRUE`. After rebuilding menu remember
   to change this back to `FALSE`.